Crossword game with python and flask
I recently finished my first major software project, aiming to provide an educational crossword product for my school assignment that can generate and display always-unique crosswords. I learned a bit of JavaScript, CSS and HTML and expanded my knowledge on Python greatly.
The repository is here: https://github.com/tomasvana10/crossword_puzzle
I know it's weird to be using both a CustomTkinter GUI and a Flask web app but since my assignment required tkinter to be used to some extent, I had no choice.
I was hoping for some feedback on my structuring of the program and my overall code, as this took a long time and I want to get as much knowledge out of it possible for future projects. If anyone wants to give feedback on the GUI aspect of my program, the repository that I linked above has the installation instructions to view the GUI.
I have included the code I wrote to generate a crossword, as this is what I struggled on the most and would love to hear ways I can improve it:
import json
import os
from random import sample, choice
from math import ceil, sqrt
from typing import Dict, Tuple, List, Union

from crossword_puzzle.definitions_parser import DefinitionsParser
from crossword_puzzle.constants import (
    CrosswordDirections, CrosswordStyle, DimensionsCalculation, Paths
)
from crossword_puzzle.errors import (
    AlreadyGeneratedCrossword, PrintingCrosswordObjectBeforeGeneration
)
from crossword_puzzle.custom_types import Placement


class Crossword(object):
    """The Crossword class creates and populates a grid with a given amount of 
    randomly sampled words from a larger set of crossword definitions in a 
    crossword-like pattern.

    Usage information:
    To begin, assign a definitions JSON to a variable by running 
    >>> Crossword.load_definitions("geography", "capitals-easy", "en")
    
    
    For simple use, instantiate the class with the required parameters and call 
    the generate() function.
    >>> crossword = Crossword("Capitals", definitions=definitions, word_count=10)
    >>> crossword.generate()
    >>> print(crossword)
    
    
    For more advanced use, use CrosswordHelper.find_best_crossword, which takes 
    an ungenerated instance of the Crossword class. This will return a crossword 
    object that is already has a populated grid and has more intersections than 
    a crossword generated with only a single attempt.
    >>> crossword = Crossword("Capitals", definitions=definitions, word_count=10)
    >>> crossword = CrosswordHelper.find_best_crossword(crossword)
    >>> print(crossword)
    
    NOTE: When inserting large amounts of words, fails with insertion may occur.
    """

    def __init__(self, 
                 name: str,
                 definitions: Dict[str, str],  
                 word_count: int, 
                 retry: bool = False
                 ) -> None:
        self.retry = retry # Flag to reattempt insertions when generating through
                           # ``CrosswordHelper.find_best_crossword``.
        if self.retry: 
            self.definitions = self._randomise_definitions(definitions)
        else: # Randomly sample ``word_count`` amount of definitions and ensure 
              # they only contain language characters
            self.definitions = DefinitionsParser._parse_definitions(definitions, 
                                                                    word_count)

        self.name = name # The name of the crossword (the crossword's directory)
        self.word_count = word_count # Amount of words to be inserted
        self.generated: bool = False # Flag to prevent duplicate generation
        self.dimensions: int = self._get_dimensions() # Side length of square grid
        self.intersections = list() # Store intersection word indices
        self.data = dict()  # Interpreted by ``main.py`` as words are inserted.
        # Example:
        # {(1, 2): {"word": "Hello", "direction": "a", "intersections": [(1, 5)], 
        #           "definition": A standard english greeting}}
        
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """Display crossword when printing an instance of this class, on which 
        ``.generate()`` has been called.
        """
        if not self.generated:
            raise PrintingCrosswordObjectBeforeGeneration
        
        # Name, word count (insertions), failed insertions, total intersections, 
        # crossword grid
        return \
            f"\nCrossword name: {self.name}\n" + \
            f"Word count: {self.inserts}, " + \
            f"Failed insertions: {self.word_count - self.inserts}\n" + \
            f"Total intersections: {self.total_intersections}\n\n" + \
            "\n".join(" ".join(cell for cell in row) for row in self.grid)

    def generate(self) -> None:
        """Create a two-dimensional array (filled with ``CrosswordStyle.EMPTY`` 
        characters)."""
        if not self.generated:
            self.generated: bool = True
            self.grid: List[List[str]] = self._init_grid()
            self._populate_grid(list(self.definitions.keys())) # Keys of definitions 
                                                               # are the words
        else:
            raise AlreadyGeneratedCrossword

    def _randomise_definitions(self, 
                               definitions: Dict[str, str]
                               ) -> Dict[str, str]:
        """Randomises the existing definitions when attempting reinsertion, 
        which prevents ``find_best_crossword`` from favouring certain word 
        groups with intrinsically higher intersections.
        """
        return dict(sample(list(definitions.items()), len(definitions)))

    def _get_dimensions(self) -> int:
        """Determine the square dimensions of the crossword based on total word 
        count or maximum word length.
        """
        self.total_char_count: int = sum(len(word) for word in
                                         self.definitions.keys())
        dimensions: int = ceil(sqrt(
                                   self.total_char_count \
                                   * DimensionsCalculation.WHITESPACE_SCALAR)) \
                                   + DimensionsCalculation.DIMENSIONS_CONSTANT
        # Assign the length of the maximum word to dimensions if it is greater
        # than dimensions. This must be done so all words can be placed in the grid.
        if dimensions < (max_word_len := (len(max(self.definitions.keys(), 
                                                  key=len)))):
            dimensions = max_word_len

        return dimensions

    def _init_grid(self) -> List[List[str]]:
        """Make a two-dimensional array of ``CrosswordStyle.EMPTY`` characters."""
        return [[CrosswordStyle.EMPTY for column in range(self.dimensions)] \
                for row in range(self.dimensions)]

    def _place_word(self, 
                    word: str, 
                    direction: int, 
                    row: int, 
                    column: int
                    ) -> None:
        """Place a word in the grid at the given row, column and direction."""
        if direction == CrosswordDirections.ACROSS:
            for i in range(len(word)):
                self.grid[row][column + i] = word[i]
            return
        
        elif direction == CrosswordDirections.DOWN:
            for i in range(len(word)):
                self.grid[row + i][column] = word[i]
            return

    def _get_middle_placement(self, 
                              word: str
                              ) -> Placement:
        """Returns the placement for the first word in a random orientation in 
        the middle of the grid. This naturally makes the generator build off of 
        the center, making the crossword look nicer.
        """
        direction: str = choice([CrosswordDirections.ACROSS, 
                                 CrosswordDirections.DOWN])
        middle: int = self.dimensions // 2

        if direction == CrosswordDirections.ACROSS:
            row = middle
            column: int = middle - len(word) // 2
        elif direction == CrosswordDirections.DOWN:
            row = middle - len(word) // 2
            column = middle

        return {"word": word, "direction": direction, 
                "pos": (row, column), "intersections": list()}

    def _find_intersections(self, 
                            word: str, 
                            direction: str, 
                            row: int, 
                            column: int
                            ) -> Union[Tuple[None], Tuple[int]]:
        """Find the row and column of all points of intersection that ``word``
        has with the grid.
        """
        intersections = list() # Stored in Tuple[row, column] form

        if direction == CrosswordDirections.ACROSS:
            for i in range(len(word)):
                if self.grid[row][column + i] == word[i]: # Intersection found
                    intersections.append(tuple([row, column + i]))

        elif direction == CrosswordDirections.DOWN:
            for i in range(len(word)):
                if self.grid[row + i][column] == word[i]:
                    intersections.append(tuple([row + i, column]))

        return intersections

    def _validate_placement(self, 
                            word: str, 
                            direction: str, 
                            row: int, 
                            column: int
                            ) -> bool:
        """Determine if a word is suitable to be inserted into the grid. Causes 
        for this function returning False are as follows:
            1. The word exceeds the limits of the grid if placed at ``row`` 
               and ``column``.
            2. The word intersects with another word of the same orientation at 
               its first or last letter, e.x. ATHENSOFIA (Athens + Sofia)
            3. Other characters are in the way of the word - not 
               overlapping/intersecting.
            4. Directly adjacent intersections are present.
        """
        if direction == CrosswordDirections.ACROSS:
            if column + len(word) > self.dimensions: # Case 1
                return False

            if word[0] == self.grid[row][column] or word[-1] \
               == self.grid[row][column + len(word) - 1]: # Case 2
                return False
            
            for i in range(len(word)):
                # Case 3
                if self.grid[row][column + i] not in [CrosswordStyle.EMPTY, 
                                                      word[i]]:
                    return False
        
                # Case 4
                if self.grid[row][column + i] == word[i] and (
                        (column + i - 1 >= 0 and self.grid[row][column + i - 1] \
                            == word[i - 1]) or
                        (column + i + 1 < self.dimensions \
                            and self.grid[row][column + i + 1] \
                            == word[i + 1])
                        ):
                    return False
        
        if direction == CrosswordDirections.DOWN:
            if row + len(word) > self.dimensions:
                return False

            if word[0] == self.grid[row][column] or word[-1] \
               == self.grid[row + len(word) - 1][column]:
                return False
            
            for i in range(len(word)):
                if self.grid[row + i][column] not in [CrosswordStyle.EMPTY, 
                                                      word[i]]:
                    return False
        
                if self.grid[row + i][column] == word[i] and (
                        (row + i - 1 >= 0 and self.grid[row + i - 1][column] \
                            == word[i - 1]) or
                        (row + i + 1 < self.dimensions \
                            and self.grid[row + i + 1][column] \
                            == word[i + 1])
                        ):
                    return False
                
        # All checks passed, this placement is valid
        return True

    def _prune_unreadable_placements(self, 
                                     placements: List[Placement]
                                     ) -> List[Placement]:
        """Remove all placements that will result in the word being directly 
        adjacent to another word,
        e.x.          or:
            ATHENS       ATHENSSOFIA 
            SOFIA
        """
        
        pruned_placements = list()

        for placement in placements:
            word_length: int = len(placement["word"])
            row, column = placement["pos"]
            readability_flag = False

            if placement["direction"] == CrosswordDirections.ACROSS:
                check_above: bool = row != 0
                check_below: bool = row != self.dimensions - 1
                check_left: bool = column != 0
                check_right: bool = column + word_length != self.dimensions
                for i in range(word_length):
                    # This letter is at an intersecting point, no need to check it
                    if (row, column + i) in placement["intersections"]:
                        continue
                    if check_above:
                        if self.grid[row - 1][column + i] != CrosswordStyle.EMPTY:
                            readability_flag = True
                            break
                    if check_below:
                        if self.grid[row + 1][column + i] != CrosswordStyle.EMPTY:
                            readability_flag = True
                            break
                    if check_left and i == 0:
                        if self.grid[row][column - 1] != CrosswordStyle.EMPTY:
                            readability_flag = True
                            break
                    if check_right and i == word_length - 1:
                        if self.grid[row][column + i + 1] != CrosswordStyle.EMPTY:
                            readability_flag = True
                            break

            elif placement["direction"] == CrosswordDirections.DOWN:
                check_above: bool = row != 0
                check_below: bool = row + word_length < self.dimensions
                check_left: bool = column != 0 
                check_right: bool = column + 1 < self.dimensions
                for i in range(word_length):
                    if (row + i, column) in placement["intersections"]:
                        continue
                    if check_above and i == 0:
                        if self.grid[row - 1][column] != CrosswordStyle.EMPTY:
                            readability_flag = True
                            break
                    if check_below and i == word_length - 1:
                        if self.grid[row + i + 1][column] != CrosswordStyle.EMPTY:
                            readability_flag = True
                            break
                    if check_left:
                        if self.grid[row + i][column - 1] != CrosswordStyle.EMPTY:
                            readability_flag = True
                            break
                    if check_right:
                        if self.grid[row + i][column + 1] != CrosswordStyle.EMPTY:
                            readability_flag = True
                            break

            if not readability_flag: # No flags were made, so this placement
                                     # can be used
                pruned_placements.append(placement)

        return pruned_placements

    def _get_placements(self, 
                        word: str
                        ) -> List[Placement]:
        """Find all placements for a given word (across and down), if valid."""
        placements = list()
        for direction in [CrosswordDirections.ACROSS, CrosswordDirections.DOWN]:
            for row in range(self.dimensions):
                for column in range(self.dimensions):
                    # The word can be inserted, so determine its intersections 
                    # and add it to the potential placements
                    if self._validate_placement(word, direction, row, column):
                        intersections = self._find_intersections(word, direction, 
                                                                 row, column)
                        placements.append({"word": word,
                                           "direction": direction,
                                           "pos": (row, column),
                                           "intersections": intersections})

        return placements

    def _add_data(self, 
                  placement: Placement
                  ) -> None:
        """Add placement information to ``self.data``."""
        self.data[(placement["pos"][0], placement["pos"][1])] = {
                            "word": placement["word"], 
                            "direction": placement["direction"],
                            "intersections": placement["intersections"],
                            "definition": self.definitions[placement["word"]]}

    def _populate_grid(self, 
                       words: List[str],
                       insert_backlog: bool = False
                       ) -> None:
        """Attempt to all the words in the grid, recursing once to retry the
        placement of words with no intersections.
        """
        if not insert_backlog: # First time execution, attempt to insert all words
            self.backlog_has_been_inserted: bool = False
            self.uninserted_words_backlog: List[str] = list()
            self.inserts: int = 0
            self.fails: int = 0
            self.total_intersections: int = 0

        if self.inserts == 0: # Place the first word in the middle of the grid
                              # (not when inserting the backlog of words).
                middle_placement: Placement = self._get_middle_placement(words[0])
                self._place_word(middle_placement["word"], 
                                 middle_placement["direction"],
                                 middle_placement["pos"][0], 
                                 middle_placement["pos"][1])
                self._add_data(middle_placement)
                self.intersections.append(middle_placement["intersections"])
                self.inserts += 1
                del words[0]
                
        for word in words: # Insert remaining words after the middle placement 
                           # is complete
            placements: List[Placement] = self._get_placements(word)
            placements = self._prune_unreadable_placements(placements)
            if not placements: # Could not find any placements, go to next word
                self.fails += 1
                continue

            # Sort placements from highest to lowest intersections
            sorted_placements = sorted(placements, key=lambda k: k["intersections"], 
                                       reverse=True)
            if not sorted_placements[0]["intersections"]: # No intersections
                if not insert_backlog: # First time execution; append words here 
                                       # for eventual reinsertion
                    self.uninserted_words_backlog.append(word)
                    continue
                else: # Reinsertion didn't help much, just pick a random placement
                    placement: Placement = choice(sorted_placements)
            else: 
                placement: Placement = sorted_placements[0]

            self._place_word(placement["word"], placement["direction"], 
                             placement["pos"][0], placement["pos"][1])
            self._add_data(placement)
            self.intersections.append(placement["intersections"])
            self.total_intersections += len(placement["intersections"])
            self.inserts += 1

        if self.backlog_has_been_inserted: # The backlog was just inserted, so 
                                           # end the function
            return

        # There are words present in the backlog and it has not been inserted yet
        if self.uninserted_words_backlog and not self.backlog_has_been_inserted:
            self.backlog_has_been_inserted = True
            # Recurse ``_populate_grid`` with ``uninserted_words_backlog``
            self._populate_grid(self.uninserted_words_backlog, insert_backlog=True) 
      
  
class CrosswordHelper:
    """Contains methods to help with the loading of crossword-related JSON files 
    and for performing optimised crossword creation with ``find_best_crossword``.
    """
    @staticmethod
    def find_best_crossword(crossword: Crossword) -> Crossword:
        """Determine the best crossword out of a amount of instantiated 
        crosswords based on the largest amount of total intersections and 
        smallest amount of fails.
        """
        name: str = crossword.name
        word_count: int = crossword.word_count
        
        attempts_db: Dict[str, int] = CrosswordHelper._load_attempts_db()
        try:
            max_attempts: int = attempts_db[str(word_count)] # Get amount of attempts 
                                                             # based on word count
        except KeyError: # Fallback to only a single generation attempt
            max_attempts = 1
        attempts: int = 0 # Track current amount of attempts

        reinsert_definitions: Dict[str, str] = crossword.definitions
        try: 
            crossword.generate()
        except: ... # The crossword is already generated for some reason
        best_crossword = crossword # Assume the best crossword is the first crossword
        
        while attempts <= max_attempts:
            # Setting the "retry" param to True will make the Crossword class 
            # only randomise the definitions it is given, not sample new random 
            # ones, for reasons explained in the ``_randomise_definitions``
            # method.
            crossword = Crossword(name=name, definitions=reinsert_definitions, 
                                  word_count=word_count, retry=True)
            crossword.generate()
            
            # Update the new best crossword if it has more intersections than 
            # the current crossword and its fails are less than or equal to the
            # current crossword's fails. Changing the fails comparison to simply
            # "less than" is too strict and results in a poor "best" crossword.
            if (crossword.total_intersections > best_crossword.total_intersections) \
                    and (crossword.fails <= best_crossword.fails): 
                best_crossword = crossword
            attempts += 1
        
        return best_crossword # NOTE: ``generate()`` has already been called 
                              # on this crossword instance.

    @staticmethod
    def load_definitions(category: str, 
                         name: str,
                         language: str = "en",
                         ) -> Dict[str, str]:
        """Load a definitions json for a given crossword."""
        # Attempt to access the localised crossword
        path = os.path.join(Paths.LOCALES_PATH, language, "cwords", category, 
                            name, "definitions.json")
        if not os.path.exists(path): # Fallback to the base crossword 
            path = os.path.join(Paths.BASE_CWORDS_PATH, category, name, 
                                "definitions.json")
        try:
            with open(path) as file:
                return json.load(file)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: # Should never happen, but who knows
            raise EmptyDefinitions

    @staticmethod
    def _load_attempts_db() -> Dict[str, int]:
        """Load ``attempts_db.json``, which specifies how many generation attempts
        should be conducted for a crossword based on its word count. This is 
        integral to the crossword optimisation process, as crossword generation
        time scales logarithmically with word count.
        """
        with open(Paths.ATTEMPTS_DB_PATH) as file: 
            return json.load(file)


if __name__ == "__main__": # Example usage – this module is normally used in 
                           # the executional context of ``main.py``
    definitions = CrosswordHelper.load_definitions("computer science",
                                                   "booleans-easy", "en")
    
    crossword = Crossword(definitions=definitions, word_count=3, name="booleans")
    crossword = CrosswordHelper.find_best_crossword(crossword)

    print(crossword)


Outstanding!
Pat yourself on the back.
Yeah, you're right, the tk / web split makes for an odd UI.
The loading / open web app buttons could probably be unified.
Since flask doesn't start up immediately, it would benefit
from an hourglass or progress bar.
Alternatively, pre-start flask so it's warming up during
the early tk interactions.
Beachball doesn't make for a great UX.
Consider forking off worker(s) that can precalculate and store puzzle
files, overlapped with the mostly idle time spent on user interactions.
Auto selecting "max words" would be a fair default setting.
cyclic intersections
Here's an interesting sub-problem to work on.
Given a set of words, identify four words
that can be placed on an empty grid to form a cycle.
Below I illustrate 8- & 9-letter horizontal words A, B,
with 6- & 8-letter vertical words C, D.
A program with a good solution to this problem could
likely leverage it to continue building cycles
outward from the center.
         D
    C    2
  A2345678
    3    4
    4    5
   B23456789
    6    7
         8

modern annotations
from typing import Dict, Tuple, List, Union

Given that you're using python 3.12,
none of those are needed, nor even encouraged.
Prefer e.g. dict[int, str], tuple[float, float] | None, list[str].
MRO
class Crossword(object):

Omit the "inherits from object" part, please.
This isn't python2; we're not trying to get a "new style" class here.
Empty files have zero length.
Text files, such as source files,
are comprised of lines terminated by newline.
So all text files end with a newline.
A file that ends with some other character
is a binary file.
Configure your editor to do the right thing
when you intend for it to write out a text file.
That will minimize spurious git diffs.
Generally, this codebase would benefit from isort + black;
I won't get into specifics.
doctest
class Crossword ...

    To begin, assign a definitions JSON to a variable by running 
    >>> Crossword.load_definitions("geography", "capitals-easy", "en")
        
    For simple use, instantiate the class with the required parameters and call 
    the generate() function.
    >>> crossword = Crossword("Capitals", definitions=definitions, word_count=10)
    >>> crossword.generate()

Wow, doctests, that's great.
But, have we been executing them? Let's try python -m doctest *.py.
Oh, dear!
    AttributeError: type object 'Crossword' has no attribute 'load_definitions' ...
    NameError: name 'definitions' is not defined ...
    NameError: name 'crossword' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Crossword'?

lint
$ ruff check crossword_puzzle/cword_gen.py
crossword_puzzle/cword_gen.py:455:9: E722 Do not use bare `except`
crossword_puzzle/cword_gen.py:504:19: F821 Undefined name `EmptyDefinitions`
Found 2 errors.

We write except Exception: in order to avoid disabling
important functionality, such as the CTRL/C handler.
(Or we catch something more specific,
so the Gentle Reader knows what the Author had in mind.)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:  # Should never happen, but who knows
        raise EmptyDefinitions

Yeah, that's the trouble with writing an error handler
which is "hard to test" so we never execute it.
A line of code that has never run is likely a buggy line.
Here, we would blow up with
NameError: name 'EmptyDefinitions' is not defined
due to a missing import.
use pathlib
                 name: str,
                 ...
        self.name = name # The name of the crossword (the crossword's directory)

Maybe a Path would be more appropriate than a str?
conventional empty containers
        self.intersections = list()  ...
        self.data = dict()  ...

There's nothing "wrong" with those assignments.
But prefer to assign = [] and = {}.
See import this.
Tim Peters asserts that

There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

str()
    def __str__(self) -> str: ...
        if not self.generated:
            raise ...

It's a bit odd to refuse to display anything.
Consider the poor maintenance engineer in a debugging session,
who tries print(foo) and the system screams "No foo for you!".
Maybe return a "not yet generated" hint?
I suspect we're reluctant to invoke .generate() because
it's heavyweight and might possibly fail, that's cool.
Consider renaming this to .print() or something else which str() won't invoke.
Consider accompanying this with def __repr__, which always succeeds.
Rather than producing a str, consider having .report()
produce a namedtuple.
set flag when it's actually True
        if not self.generated:
            self.generated: bool = True
            self.grid: List[List[str]] = self._init_grid()
            ...

Consider delaying that flag assignment a couple of lines,
just in case init or populate blow up.
I'm looking to minimize confusion in the middle of some debugging session.
adaptive shuffling
I have occasionally seen isolated unconnected words appear in the grid.
I like _randomise_definitions().
It's very simple.
Consider making it fancier by randomly discarding one
or two words, searching for a better "intersection" metric.
Encouraging a given word to have more than a single intersection
would be a worthy goal.
( ) versus \
        dimensions: int = ceil(sqrt(
                                   self.total_char_count \
                                   ...

Not sure what that \ backwhack is doing in there.
The ( ) parens have already ensured that the
continuation lines will all be part of the assigned expression.
        other_dimensions: int = (some_very_long_variable
                                 + another_giant_identifier)

Even when there's no function call involved,
it's usually preferable to tack on "extra" parens,
so as to avoid needing a \ backwhack.
For one thing, trailing whitespace after a backwhack
will change its meaning, in a confusing manner.
walrus operator
        if dimensions < (max_word_len := (len(max(self.definitions.keys(), 
                                                  key=len)))):
            dimensions = max_word_len

Consider rephrasing without the walrus, and making it unconditional.
        max_word_len = max(map(len, self.definitions.keys()))
        dimensions = max(dimensions, max_word_len)

Enum
    def _place_word(self, 
                    word: str, 
                    direction: int, ...

I'm a little surprised to see int rather than CrosswordDirection.
Also, prefer to give that pluralized class a singular spelling.
enumerate
            for i in range(len(word)):
                self.grid[row][column + i] = word[i]

Clearly this works, but consider rephrasing it as
            for i, letter in enumerate(word):
                self.grid[row][column + i] = letter

comment on the why, not the how
    def _get_middle_placement(self, 
                              word: str
                              ) -> Placement:
        """Returns the placement for the first word in a random orientation in 
        the middle of the grid. This naturally makes the generator build off of 
        the center, making the crossword look nicer.
        """

Wow, that's very helpful.
You let the code explain the How, and here you explained the Why.
Keep it up!
And in _validate_placement(), I like the strategy
of explaining everything all together,
then putting {1, 2, 3, 4} labels on the details.
Maybe we could DRY
up _validate_placement() by extracting a helper which accepts
an {ACROSS, DOWN} direction parameter?
Similarly for _prune_unreadable_placements().
organizing functions
Rather than create a CrosswordHelpers class full
of static methods, prefer to create a module,
and put ordinary def some_function() definitions in it.
swallowed exception
        try: 
            crossword.generate()
        except: ... # The crossword is already generated for some reason

Uggh!
Clean up this wart.
Minimally, log what happened so we can assess the size of the problem.
Maybe we want .generate() to return a flag instead of blowing up?
post-condition
    def find_best_crossword(
        ...
        return best_crossword # NOTE: ``generate()`` has already been called 
                              # on this crossword instance.

Prefer to delete the comment and phrase it this way:
        ...
        assert best_crossword.generated
        return best_crossword

I kind of believe comments, but might also take
them with a grain of salt, as sometimes the code
evolves and the comments don't catch up.
I always believe an assertion that executed.
test suite
The repo doesn't contain any import unittest statements.
It would benefit from automated tests.

It is clear that a lot of care went into the design of this code.
It achieves its design goals.
I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Thank you very much for your feedback, I will implement as many of your recommendations as I can.

With the DRY stuff, I believe it would make the code more easier to understand by leaving it as is. I have contemplated doing it with only half the code but it would likely make it more unreadable.

Granted, that is always a danger. Flip side is, I have seen copy-n-paste code like that where initially, or after a maintenance engineer makes changes, the two halfs are out-of-sync and don't compute same thing in the same way. Automated tests can help with catching a "whoops!" like that. // Think about the numpy API, where we often see arguments like axis=0 or axis=1. If, instead of list[list[str]] we had an ndarray, doing a 90° transpose might be a bit more natural.

When I try to run unit tests or the doc string thing it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cword_gen'"

At toplevel of repo try this: $  cd ../crossword_puzzle/ && env PYTHONPATH=. python -m doctest crossword_puzzle/cword_gen.py

works great, thanks!
